# why won't onChange event work on jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I made a very simple fiddle, but the onChange event isn't firing.  Ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/p1xelarchitect/3c5qt4a1/

```
<select multiple onChange="update()">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `update` should be global..Your load type is `onLoad`...https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/3c5qt4a1/2/

Comment: thanks. fixed. post as an answer and i'll accept it :)

Comment: I had no idea that option was in jsfiddle.

Comment: click on setting icon near javascript in javascript tab, select no wrap <head> from dropdown and run it again